# Deadlock in Java AWT's event queue

Tags: java, multithreading, awt

As far as I know AWT is considered thread-safe. Yet, I find myself in a scenario where accessing AWT from a non-`EDT` (Event Dispatch Thread) thread results in a deadlock.

**Scenario:**
A thread `X` creates a window, makes it visible, then invisible, and finally disposes of it. When setting it invisible, a `ComponentListener` is called (on the `EDT`), which disposes of the window. Meanwhile on thread `X` `dispose()` is called as well, which blocks the call, posts a dispose event for the `EDT`, and waits for the event to be dispatched. The event is for some reason never dispatched, therefore blocking thread `X` indefinitely.

Performing the `dispose()` call from thread `X` with `EventQueue.invokeAndWait()` instead will work as expected.

I posted a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) below, demonstrating the behavior. Please note that this also happens with dialogs and it doesn't need to be the main application window.

The issue was tested with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.9.101, Oracle JRE 11.0.10, and Oracle JRE 1.8.0_281.

**Questions**:

- Is there some violation of AWT's principles happening?
- Why is the dispose event never being successfully dispatched?

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Window frame = new Frame();
        frame.setSize( 200, 200 );
        frame.addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentHidden( ComponentEvent e ) {
                ((Window)e.getSource()).dispose();
            }
        } );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    
        Thread.sleep( 2000 ); // optional
    
        frame.setVisible( false ); // non-blocking call
        frame.dispose(); // blocking. thread will be stuck here aka point of no return
        //        EventQueue.invokeAndWait( () -> frame.dispose() ); // this will work
    
        System.out.println( "End of program" );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem, but you should be aware that the reason why Java AWT was abandoned by its developers however many decades ago was precisely because they found problems similar to yours that were _unsolveable_ because they were baked-in to its multi-threaded architecture. https://blog.csdn.net/coderAndy/article/details/51761691

Comment: Thank you. That is a good read. I am used to SWT where a multi-threaded UI is basically impossible. The obvious solution with the code above would be not to do any UI operations from the non-EDT thread. Sadly, this cannot be easily changed in our system, since it happens within a third party library. Therefore, I tried to get a better understanding of the problem itself.